# How to call a C++ function in a C++ Program

Tags: c++, function

Hey StackOverflow community, this question is relating to C++ Programming and how to call a function from WITHIN the same program where the calling is occurring. Also, I HAVE studied and looked up other stack overflow questions and answers, also I looked for an answer on the internet, but none of them gave me the specific answer I am looking for. Anyways, to continue with the question... I am looking for the proper/most effective way using the best practices to call a C++ function from within a C++ program. I am trying to do something like this...

```
    //Even Odd Determiner VTew
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
program();
}

int program()
{
unsigned int UserNum;
bool Odd;
bool True;

system ("cls");

cout << "User, this program is an Even/Odd Determiner.\n";
cout << "Please input a number that you would like to\n";
cout << "be determined as either Even or Odd: ";

cin >> UserNum;

system ("pause");
system ("cls");

if (UserNum % 2 == 1)
{
    cout << "Your number is odd!\n\n";
}
if (UserNum % 2 == 0)
{
    cout << "Your number is even!\n\n";
}else
{
    cout << "Invalid Input";
    program();
}



system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

But this call doesn't work, does anybody know how to do it OR another site/question that answers it, that would be great :).
BTW I am using Visual Studio 2012 Premium.
-Garrett O'Canna (Version Tew C++ Programmer and Video Game Developer)
UPDATE: Simon suggested that I state the specific problem... System hadn't been declared so, the compiler got confused because I was trying to call a function that hadn't already been declared until later in the program :).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "this call doesn't work"? Do you mean the call to "program()"? If so, what output does it produce, as compared to the output that you anticipate it should produce?

Comment: There is no way that you couldn't find the answer to this by Google searching...

Comment: @LukePark actually I bet its harder to find than you think. Its easy when you know the answer cos you know what to search for. For a new programmer this behaviour is a surprise and they dont know what to search for. He says he looked a lot - I believe him

Comment: @LukePark I looked it up (Bing Actually) and all that came up was things like how to call external programs from a C++ program and how to call C#, C, etc. programs for a C++ program.

Comment: @Simon I'll edit an update.

Comment: @pm100 @VersionTew Well the compiler error is probably a good place to start...?  `'program' was not declared in this scope.`

Comment: @Version Tew - note that calling program from inside program is not the way to go. You should use a while loop

Comment: @pm100 Yes, this is an example though of course, in an actual program I would use a dowhile loop.

Comment: Also, why am I receiving so many negative votes? I feel this is an appropriate question for this forum.

Comment: people think you didnt google hard enough

Comment: @VersionTew it's not a forum, to be technical about it.

Comment: The downvotes are mainly because you didn't read, google, or even bother to provide in the question **the error message**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function program is not known to the compiler since it's declared after your main function. You must declare it before like so

```
int program(); // Declares the function program

int main()
{
    program(); // function is declared, the compiler knows its return-type, name and parameters
    return 0;
}

// Here is the function definition
int program()
{
    // ....
}
```

A simple way to think when you're new to C/C++ is that the compiler works through the files "from top to bottom". This means you can't use a variable/method **x** before it has been declared.

You must do the same with variables. A simple example

```
#include <iostream>

// Declare an integer variable called b. The use of the word
// extern means that the variable is just declared, not initialized
extern int b;

int main()
{
    // This will compile, you have declared b above so the compiler "knows" about b
    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int b = 7; // define b
```

Comment: Very well answered! Thank you!

Comment: @VersionTew You're welcome! And welcome to the forums!

Comment: Not entirely correct. OP can also declare the entire function (or variable) above `main`. With the forward declaration approach suggested by this answer there are now two changes that must be made if `program`'s signature changes. Forget to change one and you're going to have a bad day. Fortunately the linker should catch the mistake and give you another fun error message to decode.

Comment: @user4581301 Well, given that writing the full body of the function as well above the main function would be declare AND define my answer is correct. He is required to declare the function before using it, then if he also wants to define it at the same place he declares it is up to him.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to either move the entire function so that it appears **before** `main()` or leave it where it is but declare it before `main()` by adding

```
int program();
```

before `main()`. You must either declare or define the function before `main()` - either approach will allow you to do what you want to do.

You might also want to return the return value of `program()` from your `main()` function